# Script to append Timetamp in each line in case of missing time stamp

Tags: bash, timestamp

In GC logs, each line is having timestamp at the start. but sometimes we are missing that.

I am looking to write a bash script which check if Timestamp is missing it will add some static timestamp at the beginning.

In below example there are 2 lines. 1st line is having timestamp but 2nd line doesn't.

```
2018-11-22T11:58:39.381+0100: 79412.217: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-11-22T11:58:39.381+0100: 79412.217: [ParNew: 1265865K->36835K(1380160K), 0.1419160 secs] 23560553K->22332825K(29206784K), 0.1421816 secs] [Times: user=2.39 sys=0.00, real=0.14 secs] 
79412.947: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2018-11-22T11:58:40.112+0100: 79412.947: [ParNew: 1263651K->36868K(1380160K), 0.1502318 secs] 23559641K->22334516K(29206784K), 0.1504887 secs] [Times: user=2.47 sys=0.00, real=0.15 secs]
```

1. Primary requirement is to add timestamp on each line if its missing.
2. Advance: In case of no timestamp, there is one relative time(79412.947) in epoch format. I am looking to add some static epoch time on each relative time and append at the beginning.

For example In 2nd line: 79412.947 + 153434343 = some value. Convert this value is Timestamp format and append at the beginning.

Regex to extract timestamp.
https://regex101.com/r/3CtU4y/1/

Any suggestion, helpful advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion is that bash is probably not your best choice if you have a lot of logging.

That aside, writing scripts is very much doing exactly what is asked. So it will be:

1) set up a loop to read the input lines

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $* | while read line ; do
```

2) test if the input-line starts with a timestamp (did not bother looking up the regex you supplied.

```
if echo "$line " | grep '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' ; then
    true
```

Note that, if the condition is true, `grep` will output the line, so no separate echo is needed for that.

3) Otherwise, do some things with the epoch timestamp that I can't quite understand what you want:

```
else
    estamp=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/:.*//')
    rol=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[0-9.]*://)
    # Do something with adding to the timestamp that I did not grasp
    echo "$estamp:$rol"
fi
```

Or something like that.

O yeah, close the loop

```
done
```